# How do I hold the form of terms in an output?

Tags: output-formatting

Consider the following expression:

```
EXPR = Map[Simplify@Exp[#] &, b Log[f[t]] + a (Log[f[t]] - Log[g[t]]) - c Log[g[t]]]
```

whose output is:

> $f(t)^a g(t)^{-a}+f(t)^b+g(t)^{-c}$

I want to replace the all the additions with multiplications, while otherwise retaining the form of the output. I.e., I want to hold the form of each individual term in the output of `EXPR`, so as to obtain:

> $f(t)^a g(t)^{-a} f(t)^b g(t)^{-c}$

I need to hold the forms of the terms to obtain the desired output, because once I change the additions to multiplications MMA automatically combines the terms:

```
EXPR/. {Plus -> Times}
```

> $f(t)^{a+b} g(t)^{-a-c}$

So I instead tried this, which doesn't work because it's following the standard behavior for `Hold` and thus outputting each `"EXPR[[i]]"` verbatim, rather than outputting each `EXPR[[i]]` and holding its respective form.

```
Product[Hold@EXPR[[i]], {i, 1, Length[EXPR]}]
```

> $\text{Hold}[\text{EXPR}[[i]]]^3$

Finally, these approaches (both of which give the same output) do hold the form of each term in `EXPR`'s output, but surround each with extraneous `Hold[]` syntax.

```
Product[Hold@Evaluate@EXPR[[i]], {i, 1, Length[EXPR]}]    
Product[Hold[#] &[EXPR[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[EXPR]}]
```

> $\text{Hold}\left[f(t)^b\right] \text{Hold}\left[g(t)^{-c}\right] \text{Hold}\left[f(t)^a
>    g(t)^{-a}\right]$

Comment: Do you need this because the multiplication is non-commutative? Or is there another goal here?

Comment: No, it's purely a formatting issue.  The question was motivated by my attempt to answer this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180127/how-to-collect-together-functions-of-the-same-power I've gotten close, but the next step is replacing the additions with multiplications, while otherwise holding the form.  More generally, it made me curious whether there was a way to apply Hold/HoldForm/Unevaluated, etc. to parts of an expression's output, as opposed to the input expression itself, should I encounter future cases where that type of manipulation is useful.

Comment: `Hold@Evaluate@EXPR /. {Plus -> Times}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the head of `EXPR` to `Inactive[Times]`:

```
Inactive[Times] @@ EXPR
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
EXPR /. Plus ->Inactive[Times]
```

> same result